# Can I have this type of coffee?

Tags: espresso, caffeine, health, espresso-machine

I would like to know if people normally have the type of coffee I do. I take coffee from a vending machine that has a variety of options (latte, cappuccino, espresso) of which I choose espresso. This vends 60ml of espresso (people local to me call it 60ml of decoction). This looks dark brown in color. I usually have this as such but would sometimes add 200ml of hot water to this. I never add sugar or milk to this as I hate the sweetness it adds to my coffee. What is the name of the beverage that I'm having ? Is it recommended to have 60ml of espresso (without water, milk or sugar) twice a day ? Will this have large amounts of caffeine and is it going to have an adverse effect on my health ?

I never find anyone having this type of coffee, people local to me, usually add milk to their coffee. I feel weird, and everyone suggest this might be bad for health. Am I the only one around having this type of coffee everyday ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The beverage you make by diluting vending machine "espresso" with hot water is called "poor imitation of Americano". It is hard to say how much caffeine it contains because it's not clear what this particular vending machine is filled with. It would also be wrong to speculate on its health effects without this knowledge and without knowing whether in general coffee is good for you. Unfortunately, there're many people around who drink such poor substitute of a good espresso made by a professional barista with a real espresso machine from good and fresh roasted beans.

Comment: Is this what is called espresso shot ? Does it mean that people usually have this (espresso) type of coffee (without cream, water, steamed milk or sugar but just a strong shot) ?

Comment: True espresso shot is made with espresso machine by having a small amount of hot water pass through a pressed tablet of fine ground coffee under a pressure. The resulting drink has distinctive factions with different taste and foam of oily substances on top, called crema. This is not what you'd get from a vending machine, but they'd still call it espresso for simplicity or marketing reasons.